# mathematical operations on data.table(in R)

Tags: r, matrix, data.table

I heard (from my frnd) that mathematical operations on data.table is way faster than on matrix.
I am trying to compute the dot.product of two matrix of size 30kx30k, and looking for the time taken

```
matrix1 = matrix(rexp(200, rate=.1), ncol=30000,nrow=30000)
matrix2 = matrix(rexp(200, rate=.1), ncol=30000,nrow=30000)
product = matrix1 %*% matrix2
```

Same thing I want to do with using data.table

```
dt1<- as.data.table(matrix1)
dt2<- as.data.table(matrix2)
```

Can you please tell me if there is easier way to do dot product on data.table(without converting them into matrix)?

Comment: your friend was mistaken, sorry

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The premise in this question is incorrect. 
`data.table`s, like `data.frame`s are lists of vectors.

In contrast, a matrix is a single vector with a dimension attribute.

There is an overhead associated to lists, which can be avoided if your data can fit a matrix.

`data.tables` are faster relative to data.frames (and depending on the application, lists themselves), or when using another vector as an index to iterate against.

However, for straight matrix multiplication, stick to `matrix`

Comment: How about for column operations on a matrix? e.g. m[,1]<-m[,2]^2

Comment: Is the answer still relevant or has data.table made significant progress on the topic?